# Like SSH do we have any other remote connectivity software for Ubuntu?

Tags: connection, openssh

I have seen `openssh` is mostly used for connectivity purpose. Do we have similar/more advanced connectivity software for Ubuntu?

Comment: Like such? https://mosh.mit.edu/

Comment: Correct, Yes like this you mentioned and also like `putty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try [mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/).

From the link above:

> Remote terminal application that allows roaming, supports intermittent connectivity, and provides intelligent local echo and line editing of user keystrokes.
>
> Mosh is a replacement for SSH. It's more robust and responsive, especially over Wi-Fi, cellular, and long-distance links.
>
> Mosh is free software, available for GNU/Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, Mac OS X, and Android.

So simply `sudo apt-get install -y mosh`.

What more could one want?

Answer (score 0):

Please define more advanced, ssh has an incredible amount of features:
Secure remote shell (obviously )
Secure remote copy (scp)
Portforwarding (-L )
Socks proxy (-D)
X11 forwarding and lots more.

Please describe the feature you are missing